# PHP ssh2_connect and SELinux

Tags: php, selinux

I've got a server that I was having trouble running ssh2_connect on. I realized that if I disabled SELinux it would work. I'd prefer not to do that though. Is it possible to make ssh2_connect in php work with SELinux enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. There's an selinux boolean that needs to be enabled. Run this in shell:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```